# Grunt test on cloned repository fail

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I created a webapp at work by using Yeoman's generator-webapp, did some work, and then checked it in to git.  I didn't change anything in the .gitignore, so none of the modules/bower components were in the git.

So when I got home, I tried to work on it a bit more.  So I started by cloning the repository.   Then in nodejs, I ran the following to install the project's dependencies:

```
npm install && bower install
```

I then ran `grunt test` to make sure it works, but what I got was an ERROR.

> Warning: PhantomJS unable to load "http[colon]//0.0.0.0:9001/index.html" URI. Unable to continue.

But if I ran `yo webapp` again and overwrite everything except for existing files in /app/ to keep my work intact, the generator would install a bunch of things (which I don't know what they are), and then `grunt test` would work.

As I don't want to ask my colleagues who would be cloning this project to run the risk of overwriting the files in /app/, I'd rather they install the missing components.  Can anyone tell me what to do to get this working?

Many thanks.
John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone, somewhere told me to run the following command
`npm install && bower install` to install all the dependencies and it started working.